# Bug ommits data interval - possible causes?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, facial-identification

I have encountered a strange bug and wanted to ask if someone has any idea what might be the cause.

**The bug:**

When I correlate the facial width-to-height ratio (FWHR) of NHL players with their penalty minutes per games played (PIM/GP), a section of the FWHR distribution is blank (between 1.98-2 and 2-2.022; see Figure 1). The FWHR is an int/int ratio where each int has two digits. It is extremely unlikely this reflects a true signal and is therefore most likely a bug in the code I am using.

[image: The section between FWHR 1.98-2 and 2-2.022 is blank, for no apparent reason.]

**Context:**
I know my PIM/P data is correct (retrieved from NHL's website) but the FWHR was calculated using an algorithm. The problem most likely lies within this facial measuring algorithm. I have not been able to locate the bug and therefore turn to you for advice.

**Question:**
While the code for the facial measuring algorithm is far too long to be presented here, I wanted to ask if someone might have any ideas on what might have caused it/ what I could check for?

Comment: Long, unknown code apparently has a bug.  It could be literally anything.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment...The question here revolves around a specific output (see image). This should be enough to generate ideas about what might be the cause. I am asking for those ideas (not blank statements along the lines of "bugs are tricky").

Comment: My comment remains.  With no information, nobody else can debug. I would start by looking at facial widths and facial heights separately.  Also take a face that should be in that range (distort an existing one to force that) and try running through it.  But you've got a rabbit hole to go down.  And the picture really won't help anyone who doesn't know the code/problem domain.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I like the idea of manually distorting images to track the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Nature of Ratio Distributions**

**Idea:** It should be impossible for a ratio of two 2-digit integers to fill all 2-decimal values between two integers. Could such impossible values be especially pronounced around 2.0? For example, maybe 1.99 can not be represented?

**Method:** Loop through 2-digit ints and append the ratio to a list.
Then check if the list lacks values around 2.0 (e.g., 1.99).

```py
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def int_ratio_generator():
    ratio_list = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        for j in range(1,100):
            ratio = i/j
            ratio_list.append(ratio)
    return ratio_list
    
ratio_list = int_ratio_generator()
key = 1.99 in ratio_list
print('\nis 1.99 a possible ratio from 2-digit ints?', key)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X = ratio_list
Y = np.random.rand(len(ratio_list),1)
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='C0')
plt.xlim(1.8, 2.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: See output image here]

**Conclusion:**

- Ratios from positive 2-digit integers do not fill all possible 2-decimal values between integers, and impossible values include 1.99.
- It follows that previously impossible values can be filled by including a larger range of ints, or by introducing decimal numbers within the same range.
- Furthermore, as shown by the simulation above, ratio distributions with 2-digit integers will have relatively large ranges of impossible values on either side of each integer.